# Get Stats about mmap cached percentage

Tags: mmap

This Question corresponds to Linux.

Is it possible to get how much percentage of the mmaped file is already brought to memory and are available without any page fault ?

More Explanation:

Assume the scenario I had a file say /tmp/temp_file which is say 2GB

I have free RAM of say 16GB

```
  struct stat statbuf;

   fstat(fd, &statbuf);

   char *cachedData = (char *)mmap(NULL, statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

/* Read some portion of data using cacheData

....

....

*/
```

Now assume that I open one more process of the same file, is it possible to determine how many pages are already available so that those can be read without any page faults?

Based on the percentage of the data available in cache/RAM for that file next set of logic will be determined